# How to bind form data in Spring 2.5 most efficiently?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What would be the best way how to bind a form data to model? I mean I have a simple model class:

```
public class LoginCommand {

    private String login;
    private String password;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And what would be the best way how to bind the form data to this command in Spring 2.5? Can the @InitBinder annotation help? I couldn't understand how does it work.. One way how i think it might work is bellow.

```
@Controller
public LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginAction(@ModelAttribute("loginCommand") LoginCommand lc, BindingResult result) {

        new LoginCommandValidator().validate(lc, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            // didn't validate
        } else {
            // check against db
        }

    }
}
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for login actions you probably need to look into Spring security. That aside I am going to give some insight to the more general question and suggest you look into the @RequestParam annotation...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleLogin(@RequestParam("login")    String username,
                                @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    // create constructor, remove setters to make this immutable
    LoginCommand lc = new LoginCommand(username, password);
    // more code here...
}
```

I realize there are probably multiple ways to solve this problem but I like this approach due to it's simplicity and explicitness; or more simply, it's less magic and easy to read albeit slightly verbose.

Comment: I did look it, but it's quite hard to drive into this thing with all the new stuff like the ModelAttribute, @InitBinder etc. How would the url look in this case? Like: /login/?login=login&password=password ?

Comment: The URL would be /login and the since we are using method = RequestMethod.POST the login and password will be read from the HTTP body.

Comment: So basically @RequestParam is the field name, ye?